# KaTeX Seperate Number With Commas

Tags: formatting, number-formatting, katex

I installed KaTeX on my blog, and I need a way to format a number with commas. By searching around, I found that I could use `{\small,}` wherever I needed a comma, but that seemed needlessly verbose, especially with big numbers (`1{\small,}234{\small,}567{\small,}890` is not my idea of a good time).

Thanks in advance!